# How do I access values within a JSON object?

Tags: json

I'm trying to interpret the data in a JSON feed, and post it back out in a test - now, I may be being stupid here (I'm new to all this) but I just can't get this to work.

```
var response = {"has_next":false,"number":1,"results":[{"entry_name":"Who da Mané?","total":186}]};

var json = JSON.parse(response);

var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "Entry Name: " + json.results.entry_name + " results: " + json.results.total;

document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(div);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/smayphotography/0cwkqq9d/

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: you don't need to parse to JSON as its already in JSON format, so you should skip this line:

```
var json = JSON.parse(response);
```

Second: `results` is an array, so you should loop over it not just access directly.

```
var response = {"has_next":false,"number":1,"results":[{"entry_name":"Who da Mané?","total":186}]};

results = response.results
for(i=0; i<results.length;i++ ){
  result = results[i];
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = "Entry Name: " + result.entry_name + " results: " + results.length;  
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(div);
}
```